# Qsort not working the way I expect it to with void pointers

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

So I am trying to use qsort to sort a generic array list of void pointers in C.

When I actually use the array list I am storing `Queue` pointers.

I am pretty sure I am calling `qsort` correctly

```
qsort(al->list, al->size, sizeof(void *), al->cf );
```

In my comparator function, I want to do this

```
int compareQCtgry(const void * queueA, const void * queueB)
{
    Queue * q1 = (Queue *) queueA;
    Queue * q2 = (Queue *) queueB;
    return strcmp(q1->category, q2->category);
}
```

However, I get a segfault.

But when I change it to

```
int compareQCtgry(const void * queueA, const void * queueB)
{
    Queue * q1 = *(Queue **) queueA;
    Queue * q2 = *(Queue **) queueB;
    return strcmp(q1->category, q2->category);
}
```

It works, yet it makes no sense to me. Why cast the void pointer to a `Queue **` and then dereference it when it seems like you should just be able to cast it with `Queue *`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`qsort` passes pointers to the elements of the list to the comparison routine as it sorts.  Since your list is already a list of pointers-to-`Queue`, pointers to those are pointers-to-pointers-to-`Queue`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense now.